# How to delegate ServletContext?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to override the `ServletContext.getResource()` method. So as to manage `.jsp` files myself, rather then put all `.jsp` files under `webapp/` directory.

Currently, I can patch on Jetty server, or Tomcat server, but is there a common way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change appBase property in server.xml of your tomcat server for instance :

```
 <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```